# Get index of words

Tags: python-3.x

If I have this line:

> "He is a very good man. He has a [good wife]."

And I want to extract the line, beside the [good wife] + the index of the fist word of the [good wife].

So the output will be:

> "He is a very good man. He has a [good wife], good wife: 12

I tried this

```
fi = codecs.open('file', 'r', 'utf-8')
regex = re.compile(r"\[(.*?)\]")
for line in fi.readlines():
    line2= line.split()
    mw = re.findall(regex, line2)
    print (line, mw, line2.index(mw[0]))
```

But it does give what is wanted

Can someone help?

Comment: why the index is 11? i think its 9!

Comment: ok, this is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `re.search` :

```
>>> def find(s):
...   try:
...     sub=re.search(r"\[(.*?)\]",s).group(1)
...     return sub,s.split().index('['+sub.split()[0])
...   except AttributeError:
...     return '[]'
... 
>>> print find('He is a very good man. He has a [good wife].')
('good wife', 9)
>>> print find('He is a very good man. He has a good wife.')
[]
```

note that as the result of `re.search` is `'good wife'` for grub the index of first word you need to concatenate `[` to it as `good` is not a separate word in your string.

Comment: what does group(1) do here?

Comment: @user3573552 `group(1)` is actually because of your grouping in pattern ,by default if you dont use grouping in `re.search` you need to use `group(0)` and then if you use grouping you need to specify the number of your grouping that began of 1 read more https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group

Comment: @ Kasra AD but if in file there are some lines where there are not words between brackets, like this:                                                                    "He is a very good man. He has a [good wife].
"He is a very good man. He has a good wife.                                                                       it gives me the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @user3573552 yes its obvious! now what you want to be happened in this case?

Comment: in this case I want to be inserted [ ]

Comment: @user3573552 So you need to handle your exception check out the edit!